# Branch cut of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-integration

Let $f(z) = \sqrt{(z(z-1))}$, is this reasoning sound for finding the branch cut of $f$?

$z^{1/2}$ fails to be continuous across the positive real axis i.e on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ whereas $(z-1)^{1/2}$ fails to be continuous across $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$, so we take the intersection of these two sets and conclude that the branch cut for $f$ is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$.

I am not sure if this approach is correct.

Comment: You should take the union of cuts, not the intersection. It can be helpful to think of what branch of the square root $\sqrt w$ you want to take, and then what is the locus where $w=z(z-1)$ belongs to the cut.

Comment: Oh I see we are just considering where the whole function fails to be continuous (considering the principal branch for example) so need the whole positive real axis?

Comment: There is no “the branch cut” for a function. A branch cut is just a set composed of a finite number of lines (with no, one, or two of its ends going to infinity) such that if you remove this set from the domain, then the function becomes single valued (prescribing a value in a base point). In this case, you could remove for example $(-\infty, 0] \cup [1, \infty)$ or just $[0,1]$. Both choices would lead to a single valued function.

Comment: Is this a good approach: 1.find branch points by considering where the function is undefined e.g $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ is undefined at $z=0$ and $z=1$ 2.Restrict domain of $\mathbb{C}$ so that we can't draw a closed path around the branch points, this defines a branch cut, i.e the complement of this restricted set of points. Then we can define a branch from here by defining the function on the restricted domain?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, for functions like $\sqrt z$, $\mathrm{Ln}(z)$ and $z^\alpha$, there are infinitely many branches. For example, the accepted, standard definition of $\mathrm{Ln}(z)$ from $\ln z$ is defined as follows:
$$
\mathrm{Ln}(z)=\ln r+i\theta\quad,\quad -\pi<\theta\le\pi.
$$
With this definition, the non-analytical branch of $\mathrm{Ln}(z)$ is $z=re^{i\pi}$ for $r\ge 0$. However, defining $\mathrm{Ln}(z)$ as $\ln r+i\theta$ with $-\pi+\theta_0<\theta\le\pi+\theta_0$, would leave us with a non-analytical branch of $z=re^{i\pi+i\theta_0}$ with $r\ge 0$. Same thing happens with $\sqrt{z}$. For example, we can define
$$
\sqrt{z}=r^\frac{1}{2}\exp\left(i\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\quad,\quad -\pi<\theta\le \pi,
$$where the non-analytical branch would again be $z=re^{i\pi}$ for $r\ge 0$. Back to your question, since $z(z-1)$ is complete, the non-analytical branch of $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ is $z(z-1)=-r$ for $r\ge 0$, or $z\in \{(x,0):0\le x\le 1\}\cup \{(\frac{1}{2},y):y\in \Bbb R\}$.